# R: problems with understanding error messages related to making polygons

Tags: r, error-handling, vegan

I have an issue in R.
I am doing some NMDS tests using the vegan package and it has been going pretty well so far, untill I tried to use this code to draw polygons in my NMDS:

```html
ordiplot(nmds,type = "n")
colors<-c(rep("blue",22),rep("red",24))
treat<-c(rep("ngs",22),rep("gs",24))
for(i in unique(treat)) {
  ordihull(nmds$points[grep(i,treat),],groups = treat[treat==i],draw = "polygon",col = colors[grep(i,treat)],label = F)
}
```

Doing so gives me this error message:

```html
Error in chull(X) : finite coordinates are needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In complete.cases(pts) & !is.na(groups) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In groups == is & kk :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I honestly don't know what it is caused by. I have found someone who had the same issue, and a suggestion was that there were to few observations in some of the treatments. I doubt that is the case here, but I can't dismiss it, simply because I don't know how to check for this.
My data contains 46 observations and two treatments.
Here is the data, the treatment changes at observation 23 [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_cL49_uu1UXF_uasg_QFcgfawtaSayuN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The error message says that you have arguments of different lengths. Why do you do things with a `for()` loop? Have you tried command `ordihull(nmds, treat, col=c("blue","red"), draw="polygon")` instead of your `for(){}` loop?

Comment: Honestly, it boils down to inexperience. I took the code from another example, and it worked. What I can see is that it makes it easier to know which colour refers to which treatment, because I define that myself. However, that is an easily dealt with issue. Your suggestion works just as well. Also, using your suggestion doesnt give me the error message anymore! Thank you so much for your help.